# ServiceStack Redis client behaviour for non-existant key

Tags: redis, servicestack

In the Redis documentation when you call the Get operation and key doesn't exist, it is supposed to return Nil. (Source: http://redis.io/commands/get)

How does the ServiceStack client handle this?  Does it reutn null, or do I need to use Exists, ContainsKey?

Is there another approach to check if key exists and return value using one request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get null back if you try to get a key that does not exist.

There are lots of different ways to get keys using IRedisClient, but here's an example:

[GetValue()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/e0f01bb303f73e4811a4971c2988f1ed1b50435d/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L132)

If you're interested IRedisNativeClient goes directly against the metal in a 1-1 command fashion.

You can do multiple things in one request by using a pineline or transaction.  For example:

```
using(var pipeline = client.CreatePipeline())
{
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.GetSetCount("key1"), count => count1 = count);                
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.GetSetCount("key2"), count => count2 = count);
    pipeline.QueueCommand(r => r.GetSetCount("key3"), count => count3 = count);
    pipeline.Flush();
}
```